# pandas data and scikit learn

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

I have a pandas dataset with more than 300 predictors which are both continuous and categorical. The target variable is categorical and has values 0 or 1. I am going to perform logistic regression and I want to use the recursive feature selection from scikit learn module to obtain a shortlist of predictors. I know how to assign the target variable in the rfe.fit(x,y) function. How do I allocate all the other variables to x matrix?

thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by "allocate all the other variables to x matrix"? For categorical values, you already have 0 or 1. For other features, you need to normalize them, so that their values also fall into [0,1]. Is that what you are looking for?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `df.drop()` [as it is described here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html) Please remember that when dropping columns you should set `axis=1`

Answer (score 0):

You said that you want to use scikit-learn [feature selector](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/feature_selection.html).

You pass your input matrix to a feature selector (e.g. `SelectKBest`) and then you can use the new features in the classifier.

```
# X, y = your features and labels
sel = SelectKBest(chi2, k=2) # or any other feature selector
X_new = sel.fit_transform(X, y)

# clf = classifier of your choice
clf.fit(X_new, y)
```